# General Commutator for Spherical Tensors (reformulated)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, representation-theory

Edit: I think what I was looking for wasn't very well understood, so I'm reformulating my question to make it clearer. Hope this helps.

In the book of "Angular Momentum: An Illustrated Guide to Rotational Symmetries for Physical Systems" (p. 309), the Racah definition for the commutators of spherical operators is given by:

\begin{align}
[J_0,T_{kq}]&=[J_z,T_{kq}]=qT_{kq} \\
[J_{\pm 1},T_{kq}]&=\sqrt{(k\mp q)(k\pm q+1)}T_{kq\pm1}
\end{align}

Using the commutator for spherical operators provided by Sakurai in *Modern Quantum Mechanics* (p. 239):

$$[J\cdot n, V_{q}^{(k)}]=\sum_{q'}V_{q'}^{(k)}\langle k,q'|J\cdot n|k,q\rangle$$

And by taking $n=z$ and $n=x\pm i y$ respectively, as well as applying the well known eigenvalue equations:
\begin{align}
J_z|j,m\rangle & =\hbar m |j,m\rangle\delta_{m,m'} \\
J_\pm|j,m\rangle & =\hbar\sqrt{(j\mp m)(j\pm m+1)} \delta_{j,j'}\delta_{m',m\pm 1}
\end{align}
We can easily deduce the Racah commutators given at the beginning (for a detailed proof, see p. 21 of: http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/1011/notes/wigeck.pdf).

Now, I've been working on an exercise which asks to generalize the above commutators for the case $k=1$, and show that by expressing the generators of rotations $J$ in the spherical basis $J_q$, the commutators with a spherical operator can be rewritten as:

$$[J_{q},V_{q'}]
=(-1)^{q}\hbar\sqrt{2}\langle 1,q+q';1,-q|1,q'\rangle V_{q+q'}$$

However, I don't see how to combine both commutators for into this single relation or how to derive this expression in the first place. While there's a similar equation in the book of "Angular Momentum", the author just states it like that and so far I haven't found any detailed derivation of this last commutator.

Over the past week, I tried several methods to derive this expression, but most of them ended in me already knowing the general expression and proving particular cases. Nevertheless, I'm looking for a proof in the same spirit as the ones I did for the first two commutators.

$\ $

Example:

I tried the following. Let's start with the basics and set $k=1$ Recalling the commutator in (Sakurai):

$$[J\cdot n, V_{q}]=\sum_{q'}V_{q'}\langle 1,q'|J\cdot n|1,q\rangle$$

Now taking $n=(n_0,n_{+1},n_{-1})$, where $(n_0,n_{+1},n_{-1})$ are the components of the spherical base:

$$[J_{q'}, V_{q}]=\sum_{q''}V_{q''}\langle 1,q''|J_{q'}|1,q\rangle$$

Using the Wigner-Eckart theorem, with $j=j'$:

$$\langle j,m'|T_q^{(k)}|j,m\rangle=\langle j,m;k,q|j,m\rangle \frac{\langle j||T^{(k)}||j\rangle}{\sqrt{2j'+1}}$$

With some algebra (see https://www.ipnl.in2p3.fr/perso/bennaceur/emr.pdf), we can prove that the reduced matrix element is:

$$\langle j||T^{(k)}||j'\rangle=\hbar \sqrt{j(2j+1)(j+1)}$$

Reintroducing into the W-E theorem:

$$\langle j,m'|T_q^{(k)}|j,m\rangle=\langle j,m;k,q|j,m\rangle \frac{\hbar \sqrt{j(2j+1)(j+1)}}{\sqrt{2j+1}}$$

Substituting now in the commutator given in (Sakurai), with $j=j'=1$:

$$[J_q, V_{q'}]=\sum_{q'}V_{q'}\langle 1,q'|J_q|1,q\rangle$$

$$[J_q, V_{q'}]=\sum_{q'}V_{q'}\langle 1,q;1,q|1,q'\rangle\hbar \sqrt{2}$$

Which should somehow reduce to:

$$[J_{q},V_{q'}]
=(-1)^{q}\hbar\sqrt{2}\langle 1,q+q';1,-q|1,q'\rangle V_{q+q'}$$

But I can't find a way to do it, assuming my procedure is correct.

Comment: This is just the relation between $3j$ and CG coefficients.  You can check that the square root factor is actually proportional to the appropriate CG.

Comment: Thanks, I know that for the last commutator the two lines are connected by the relation between the $3j$ and CG coefficients. However, I wanted to know how did the author derived the last commutator (how did the $3j$ or the CG coefficients arose in the first place).

Comment: Compare $\sqrt{(j\mp m)(j\pm m+ 1)}$ with analytical expression for CG...  The more general expression lies in the Wigner-Eckart theorem.

Comment: That seems like a good idea, I'll try it in a while and comment if I succeed to finding it.

Comment: Well I tried doing it but the general expression of the C-G coefficients (which has sums of products of permutations) is extremedly hard to reduce without computer, so I ended just comparing individual cases again. Not sure if this approach is correct or there's a formal demonstration.

Comment: What's wrong with using a computer? Three-j symbols are a special function like any other. Mathematica's `ThreeJSymbol` function can be quite easily `Simplify`ed on the form you've given to provide a symbolic-computation proof of the equalities you're concerned with using pointwise checks on the three values of $\sigma$. If you're going to go the full depth into understanding the deeper structures used by the author to produce those expressions then it is indeed worth getting into the full hassle of 3j symbols, but if you just want a working proof, symbolic computation is plenty.

Comment: I think I should reformulate my question, from the comments I see it isn't clear what I want. I meant I want to deduce the last commutator from the first two commutators, not proving that the last commutator is true by substituting values (which is what I did using Mathematica).

Comment: Yeah, this is substantially clearer. You almost certainly have a typo in the Sakurai formula, though - you should double-check the labelling between q and q'.

Comment: My feeling is that your explicit eigenvalue calculations are a red herring. If this was on an explicit coordinate representation I would try to reshape the Sakurai identity into a triple-product integral of spherical harmonics, express that as a 3j symbol, and bridge from there to the CG coefficient. There's probably an 'abstract' route that doesn't require the coordinate representation, though. (Not that it'd necessarily be more enlightening.)

Comment: I checked the labelling of the Sakurai, the type is on the $[J,V_q]$. I didn't really thought about passing from spherical harmonics to the 3j symbol, but it could work since I know the connection between 3j symbol and the CG coefficient. The challenge would be to find an integral which can be expressed as the product of three spherical harmonics so I can reduce it to the product of 3j symbols. I'll check it anyway to see if I can arrive to something.

Comment: If you're OK with forcing that representation, then it's certainly doable. I'm a bit hesitant to post that because it doesn't look like it really fully pins down what the connection is.

Comment: Well to tell the truh I haven't fully developed the full idea yet, as I've been working on another exercise. However, I'll keep you updated if I managed to find a proper demonstration of the commutator of interest.

Comment: I've added some additional typo fixes which are reasonably obvious. Please double-check that they're correct - and you probably want to check whether they require further downstream fixes.

Comment: ... and as a further comment, you're pulling results from so many disparate sources that there's a huge likelihood of sign errors and constants coming in through mismatched conventions in your different sources. You should be *much* more explicit in terms of where you're getting which statement, including an absolute requirement of a full bibliographic reference of where you got your target statement.

Comment: My target statement was a problem proposed in my graduate QM course, so I'm not sure where the professor got the problem. I double checked the sources of my attempt but didn't succeed even with the last idea.